# Pass an object's function as parameter to another function

Tags: python

I have function that will get the data from the cache if it exists else it will query the DB and save it in the cache.

```
def get_ref_from_cache_or_db(obj, key, duration=60):
data = get_routes_from_cache(key=key)
if data:
    response = json.loads(data)
else:
    response = obj.fetch().to_dict()
    set_routes_to_cache(key=key, duration=duration, value=json.dumps(response))
return response
```

Sometimes I have to return different results from the same object, for example I need to call

```
response = obj.fetch().to_dict()
```

or

```
response = obj.fetch().to_other_dict()
```

If it were a simple simple function call my code would simply be:

```
def get_ref_from_cache_or_db(func, key, duration=60):
    data = get_routes_from_cache(key=key)
    if data:
        response = json.loads(data)
    else:
        response = func()
        set_routes_to_cache(key=key, duration=duration, value=json.dumps(response))
    return response
```

But in this case I don't know how to pass the function that will be called from the object returned from another function, i.e i want to call something like this `get_ref_from_cache_or_db(obj.fetch.to_dict, key, duration)`. I don't want to call the `fetch()` beforehand because it will always get the data from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the `fetch()` only when needed, you can use a lambda: `get_ref_from_cache_or_db(lambda: obj.fetch().to_dict() , key, duration)`

Comment: Can you please explain more how this works?

Comment: A lambda is a one liner function definition, so here you create a function that calls your function. I would suggest to read more about lambdas.